# IBM Mobile First - Generate HTML for mobileweb

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

We need to create the index.html for the mobilewebapp on Mobile Frist project dynamically on server side.

It's possible to use javascript or java to create index.html ?
Or the only way it's to load a html fragment calling an Adpter ?

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 the index.html file is generate when you create the project in MobileFirst Studio. The feature you want is not available built-in.

You could build this feature yourself to create the file and place it in the in the project programmatically and then invoking the build and deploy steps programmatically as well.

In v8.0 you create the HTML file yourself (there are no projects anymore). Here it is simpler to create this file and handle it as there is no deployment required other than registering the app - once.

I suggest that you will look into v8.0.

Comment: We need to create HTML file on every request (dynamic id for text-input and dynamic js inclusion). I will investigate on v8.0 ...